# How to make RASTER from irregular point data without interpolation

Tags: r, raster, r-grid

I was trying to make a raster image from an irregularly spaced point database. The data looks like-

```
> head(s100_ras)
         x       y         z
1 267573.9 2633781 213.29545
2 262224.4 2633781  69.78261
3 263742.7 2633781  51.21951
4 259328.4 2633781 301.98413
5 264109.8 2633781 141.72414
6 255094.8 2633781  88.90244
```

I want these 'z' values within a mesh which I created by

```
# Create a fine mesh grid
my_mesh=expand.grid(seq(min(s100_ras$Y),max(s100_ras$Y),l=100),
                    seq(min(s100_ras$X),max(s100_ras$X),l=100))
```

I also want the z-values to be assigned as 'NA' for those mesh points that are outside the data points. The points over the mesh looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vYzlwTkhvaHBFTnc/edit?usp=sharing
when I plot

```
plot(my_mesh)
points(s100_ras$Y, s100_ras$X, pch="*", col='blue')
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to build on this, the following steps don't work because my mesh grid and data points are not of the same scale!!

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
xyz<-cbind(my_mesh, s100_ras)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(xyz)
image(r)
```

If I try to make a raster just by using the data points (without any mesh), R throws an error since my data is irregularly spaced!

```
library(sp)
s100_ras <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = s100_ras$Y, y = s100_ras$X), 
                       z = as.vector(s100_ras$mean))
coordinates(s100_ras) <- ~x+y
proj4string(s100_ras) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84")
gridded(s100_ras) = TRUE

suggested tolerance minimum: 0.916421 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

Moreover, I was trying to play with 'rasterize' function (for irregular grids) of 'raster package', but couldn't get a way with it :(. I know how to interpolate and make a regular grid, but for the sake of originality, I want to AVOID interpolation. Is it possible to make a raster of irregularly spaced data points without idw or kriging methods? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear-cut solution to the answer has been provided by Robert here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79062/how-to-make-raster-from-irregular-point-data-without-interpolation