# Error: in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : dimension 1: coordinate intervals are not constant

Tags: r, stack, raster, spatial, dismo

I'm new working in programming languages at all, but here I'm using R language and I need some help, I'm trying to learn how to make a consensus in SDM. The idea is create a raster and then, use the stack() function. But when I try to apply this on a document, using the gridded() function on the presente.txt file, I got the following error:

`in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant`

The document in question is a .txt file that look like this:
[presente.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3J0i.png)
What I'm not understanding is that: I have others .txt files on the code and they run just fine in the code: [example .txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGtqj.png)

My code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17z5Kd8ahzNx0uIgBUGgbn_xIhfNBjmQd/view?usp=sharing

Hope it's reproducible, really need to solve this

Note: I realize now that the first file have 49.502 rows and the others 49.504, don't know if it's saying something

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to the site Mariana! Without the input data it is quite difficult to understand the issues, and the code is quite long 200+ lines which make it a bit challenge to figure out. Though I assume that the errors occured at one of the line between `22 -> 25`
Though I think your question could be duplicated with this one. Can you check this link:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79062/how-to-make-raster-from-irregular-point-data-without-interpolation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make RASTER from irregular point data without interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306020/how-to-make-raster-from-irregular-point-data-without-interpolation)

Comment: @SinhNguyen Thanks! It worked! Thank you so so much.